# Configure gradle.properties android.enableAapt=false on travis yml file

Tags: android, continuous-integration, travis-ci, aapt, continuous-delivery

In my android's `gradle.properties` I have the following:

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

My `gradle.properties` is located in my `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` in my local machine.

I am wondering how I can add `android.enableAapt=false` to my yml file.

I tried to add it under global but that didn't work there was no errors but in `robolectric` it needs to be set if you are using `gradle:3.0.0-beta3`.

```
language: android

jdk: oraclejdk8

env:
  global:
    - ANDROID_TARGET=android-25
    - ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
    - android.enableAapt2=false

android:
  components:
  - tools
  - platform-tools
  - build-tools-25.0.3
  - android-25
  - extra-android-m2repository
  - sys-img-${ANDROID_ABI}-${ANDROID_TARGET}


licenses:
  - android-sdk-license-.+
  - '.+'

script:
    - ./gradlew --daemon build jacocoTestReport --info

after_success:
    - bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
```

Below is the configuration file that is on travis-ci

```
{
  "language": "android",
  "jdk": "oraclejdk8",
  "android": {
    "components": [
      "tools",
      "platform-tools",
      "build-tools-25.0.3",
      "android-25",
      "extra-android-m2repository",
      "sys-img-${ANDROID_ABI}-${ANDROID_TARGET}"
    ]
  },
  "licenses": [
    "android-sdk-license-.+",
    ".+"
  ],
  "script": [
    "./gradlew --daemon build jacocoTestReport --info"
  ],
  "after_success": [
    "bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)"
  ],
  "global_env": "ANDROID_TARGET=android-25 ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a android.enableAapt2=false",
  "group": "stable",
  "dist": "precise",
  "os": "linux"
}
```

Class under test:

```
public class RecipeListViewHolderTest extends BaseRobolectricTestRunner {
    @Inject Map<Integer, RecipeListViewHolderFactory> viewHolderFactories;
    @Inject @LayoutRes int recipeItem; /* This is injected return R.layout.recipe_item; */

    private RecipeListViewHolder recipeListViewHolder;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        getTestComponent().inject(RecipeListViewHolderTest.this);
        final Context context = ShadowApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext();

        final View view = View.inflate(
                context,
                recipeItem,
                new LinearLayout(context));

        recipeListViewHolder = viewHolderFactories.get(Constants.RECIPE_LIST).create(view);
        assertThat(recipeListViewHolder, is(notNullValue()));
    }

    private Recipe createRecipeData() {
        Recipe recipe = new Recipe();
        recipe.setName("Test Brownies");
        recipe.setServings(10);

        return recipe;
    }

    @Test
    public void testRecipeDataIsPopulated() {
        recipeListViewHolder.populateDate(createRecipeData());

        assertThat(recipeListViewHolder.tvQuantity.getText().toString(), is("Quantity: 10"));
        assertThat(recipeListViewHolder.tvRecipeName.getText().toString(), is("Test Brownies"));
    }
}
```

Robolectric:

```
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class,
        sdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP,
        packageName = "me.androidbox.busbybaking",
        application = BusbyBakingApplication.class)
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public abstract class BaseRobolectricTestRunner {

    protected TestBusbyComponent getTestComponent() {
        return DaggerTestBusbyComponent.builder()
                .mockRecipeListModule(new MockRecipeListModule())
                .mockRecipeSchedulersModule(new MockRecipeSchedulersModule())
                .build();
    }
}
```

The travis-ci error log:

```
me.androidbox.busbybaking.recipieslist.RecipeListViewHolderTest > testRecipeDataIsPopulated FAILED
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: me.androidbox.busbybaking:layout/recipe_item
        at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAssetManager.loadXmlResourceParser(ShadowAssetManager.java:391)
        at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.loadXmlResourceParser(ShadowResources.java:211)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1049)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:412)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:18415)
        at me.androidbox.busbybaking.recipieslist.RecipeListViewHolderTest.setup(RecipeListViewHolderTest.java:41)
```

I think that the travis-ci cannot find where the res folder is as the layout/recipe_item cannot be found:

```
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: me.androidbox.busbybaking:layout/recipe_item
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not mixing `android.enableAapt` with `android.enableAapt2`? You cannot disable AAPT, you can disable AAPT2.

Comment: Also you have written `android.enableApat=false` in your `yml` file, it should be `Aapt` instead of `Apat`.

Comment: That was my mistake in the travis-ci. It was a typo. I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: I have updated my question with the exact error I am getting. To answer your question on ~/.gradle/gradle.properties is because I have set the build ramdisk `android.buildCacheDir=/mnt/ramdisk/buildCache`and I didn't want to export that to travis-ci. However, I have moved the gradle.properties to my project director and removed that line. I am trying again to build on travis-ci

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are disabling AAPT2 in global properties file `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` instead of project properties file `/yourproject/gradle.properties`.

Comment: That worked for travis-ci, thanks. However, just a quick question. In my local project will android studio use the global ~/.gradle/grade.properties or the local ~/myProject/gradle.properties?

Comment: Global properties has precedence over local properties, i.e. if you define variable with the same name in both global and project `gradle.properties` file, than the one from global will have higher priority.

Answer (score 0):

It could be, that you have copied the name of the gradle.properties file from this *official* tweet:

https://twitter.com/androidstudio/status/875311569219006464

Unfortunettely the text *gradle.propertіes* was written with cyrilic 'i' :

```
echo 'gradle.propertіes' | hexdump -C
```

> 00000000  67 72 61 64 6c 65 2e 70  72 6f 70 65 72 74 **d1 96**  |gradle.propert..|
>   00000010  65 73 0a                                          |es.|

`0xd196` is in UTF8 'CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER BYELORUSSIAN-UKRAINIAN I'.

In this case the file will not be recognized and used.